# Daterange picker lable selected after date get

Tags: php, jquery, daterangepicker

Can any one help me for label selected like

If any one click on "Yesterday" date range picker selected Yesterday

Please see image for more details -
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzlid.png)

```js
$('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
      {
        // startDate: moment().startOf('month'),
        // endDate: moment().endOf('month'),
        startDate: '',
        endDate  : '',
        ranges   : {
          'All time'       : ['',''],
          'Today'       : [moment(), moment()],
          'Yesterday'   : [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
          'Last week' : [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
          'Last 30 days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
          'This month'  : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
          'Last month'  : [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        locale: {
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A'
        }
      },
      function (start, end) {
        console.log(start._isValid);
        if(!start._isValid) $('#joiningdaterange').val('');
        else $('#joiningdaterange').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '  to  ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved now

Add this code inside function (start, end)

```
  setTimeout(function(){
          $("#daterange-btn").trigger('click');
          console.log($(".ranges ul li.active").text());
          $(".dp-lable").html($(".ranges ul li.active").text());
          $(".ranges ul li.active").trigger('click')
          $(".applyBtn").trigger('click')
        }, 100);
```